# What rewards are available in Fishing Tournament?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

I’ve encountered my first fishing tournament. I can get points and redeem them for a seemingly random rewards.

This raises several highly related queries.

Is the number of points redeemed linked to the reward? How many points should I aim for? What cool stuff can I get? Is there any way to turn off those ####ing eggs?

Comment: Please try to stick to one question at a time

Answer (score 1):

There's a total of 13 "swag" items you can get. You can exchange 10 points to get a random one of these:

- Anchor Statue
- Fish Doorplate
- Fish Drying Rack
- Fish Pochette
- Fish Print
- Fish-print Tee
- Fish Rug
- Fish Umbrella
- Fish Wand
- Fishing Rod Stand
- Fresh Cooler
- Marine Pop Wallpaper
- Tackle Bag

You also get Bronze/Silver/Gold Fish Trophy at 100/200/300 points earned per tourney day.

Comment: Is the Tourney score cumulative? Or does the point count reset with each tournament?

Comment: After the tournament ended, CJ confirmed that points are cumulative between tournaments.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems the items are drawn out of a bag, ie. you don't get duplicates until you've gotten at least one of each

Comment: That was my experience as well.